# Unable to create a temporary table from a select query with multiple joins. Throws 'Duplicate column name 'id'

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, inner-join

This is the query that is causing the problem:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE fetchedCropVariety ENGINE = MEMORY 
SELECT *
     , hz.zoneName
     , i.fullImageUrl
     , i.previewImageUrl
     , u.userName
  FROM seedrecord s
  LEFT 
  JOIN HardinessZone hz 
    ON hz.id = s.hardiness_zone_id
  JOIN image i 
    ON s.id = i.seedrecord_id 
  JOIN members u 
    ON s.FK_USER = u.id 
WHERE s.id = 1 
   AND s.deleted = FALSE;
```

When i execute this query it throws the error `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'`
There are no duplicate columns named id in the table `seedrecord` so this is caused by one or more id columns from the other tables that are only used to join them in order to retrieve `zoneName` and `fullImageUrl`.

When i remove `*,` from the query the query does run but all the fields from `seedrecord` are omitted. It must be the `id` column from `seedrecord` that is clashing somehow with the id columns from `hardinessZone` and `members` but I am not trying to include the id fields of those 2 tables into the temporary table i want to create so this error is really puzzeling me.

Can anyone tell me what i can do to stop this error from occurring?

Thank you

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't make

```
select *
```

It will take all clomuns that you have in your From Clause

And you have the at least two Columns that are namend id

MAke instead

```
S.*,u.*
```

and so on

Comment: are you saying that * will take all the columns from all tables (seedrecord, hardinesszone, members) because that would explain the duplicate column error. If thats the case could you explain to me why it is also selecting everything from the join tables? I mean I am not having HardinessZone or Image etc right after `FROM` like SeedRecord is.

Comment: because that is what a select * makes it slect all available columns, also that is what a join makes it joins all column from two tbales with a criteria to join them